# Visual Studio not autocompleting custom imports

Tags: python, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, I have a file Class1.py with various classes/methods that I would like to use in some other file Class2.py in the same folder. By including

```
import Class1
```

I can run these methods, but, I am not able to see any of these classes/methods in the autofill when I type

```
Class1.
```

in the editor. Furthermore, I am not able to see any of my docstrings when I hover over one of my uses of a class/method.

Is there a way to get Visual Studio to recognize/autofill the classes/methods I import between files, in particular, so that class/method names will autocomplete and so that I can quickly view the docstrings?